# Scheduling back up in c#

Tags: c#, windows, timer, scheduled-tasks

I am writing a software for a company in c# which is intended to run on windows platform.

One of my requirements is to allow the user to schedule back ups.

That is, the user will set a time where the database will be backed up automatically by the computer.

On the linux platform I would have use crons but I am a bit lost on the windows platform. I do not want the software itself to be actually opened for the back up to run. I want it to be carried out even if the software itself is not running.

My best bet is to use windows scheduler or create a custom service which will run at start up.

Can anyone point me to how to actually achieve this? Any constructive suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use the task scheduler that's integrated in Windows?

Comment: When you say database what do you mean? If you mean something like Sql Server then using the database's own methods of scheduling backups would be best and these can be scripted for most db solutions (though letting your users control this is not necessarily wise). If you are backing up a custom application data store then either windows scheduler or a custom service would work fine - those are how you schedule things in a windows environment.

Comment: Can you guys point me to some documentation that for using windows scheduler within c#?

Comment: You can find a wrapper on codeplex.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For info the Windows "AT" command is somewhat similar to cron.  You can get help from the command line thus:

```
AT /?
```

I wouldn't necessarily recommend it for a db backup.  Either create a Windows scheduled task, or to backup a SQL Server database, use SQL server's built in scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to create a windows service to handle the task. Then you could write any code needed (e.g. Backup / Email logs, etc) quickly and easily, and it would work w/o your application running.

There are ways to accomplish the same task with Task Scheduler built into windows, but just an alternative that I would prefer.